# How to use the method amazonSQSClient() in the main class?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new in **Spring Boot**. Does anyone know how to **call** the method **amazonSQSClient()** in the main class?

```
@Configuration
public class AWSConfiguration {
    @Value("${aws.access.key.encrypted}")
    private String amazonAWSAccessKey;

    @Value("${aws.secret.key.encrypted}")
    private String amazonAWSSecretKey;

    @Value("${aws.region.encrypted}")
    private String amazonAWSRegion;

    @Bean
    public AmazonSQS amazonSQSClient() {

        AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(amazonAWSAccessKey, amazonAWSSecretKey);
        AmazonSQS client = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(amazonAWSRegion)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials)).build();

        return client;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to.  That's the point of using the `@Bean` annotation, Spring will inject an instance of `AmazonSQS` whenever you need one.  So, you might have a class like this that uses the SQS client:

```
@Service
public class QueueService {

    private AmazonSQS amazonSQS;

    @Autowired
    public QueueService(AmazonSQS sqs) {
        this.amazonSQS = sqs;
    }
}
```

The Spring framework is smart enough to see that it needs to inject an instance of `AmazonSQS`, and by marking the method `amazonSqsClient` with the `@Bean` annotation, you are telling Spring to use that method whenever it needs to create an instance of `AmazonSQS`.